# Vue Directive Reactivity value

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am using a custom v-directive "v-clip" and it requires a value. In my case i want to use 'data binding'. Which means the value for v-clip can change on the fly from other interactions on the website.

In this case I've implemented a simple example where every time a user clicks a button called 'Counter' it increments the value by 1. How can I retrieve the most up to date value when the user clicks on the custom directive which prints to the console.

Is there a way i can use vnode or something to retrieve the value. I would imagine the directive would be able to someone get the updated value.

**clip directive**

```
Vue.directive('clip', {
      bind: (el, binding, vnode) => {
        const clickEventHandler = (event) => {
          console.log(binding.value)
        }
        el.addEventListener('click', clickEventHandler)
      },
    })
```

It's used like this where the variable `counter` is dynamically changed when a button is clicked in the ui.

```
<div v-clip="counter">Clip A {{ counter }}</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [Vue.js 2 guide](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/custom-directive.html#Directive-Hook-Arguments):

> If you need to share information across hooks, it is recommended to do so through element’s dataset.

So, if I understand correctly your question, you can try in the following way:

```js
Vue.directive('clip', {

    bind: (el, binding) => {

        const clickEventHandler = () => {
            console.log(el.getAttribute('data-clipvalue'))
        }

        el.addEventListener('click', clickEventHandler)
        el.setAttribute('data-clipvalue',binding.value)
        
    },

    update: (el,binding) => {
        el.setAttribute('data-clipvalue',binding.value)
    }

})
```